# configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

Tags: linux, gcc, gnu, thrift, msys

I am trying to Build and Install the Apache Thrift compiler and libraries

I had to type this command is shown in instructions
`./configure && make`
But I get this error:

```
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/PATH/TO/thrift-0.9.3':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

When I type in my command prompt
`gcc --version` I get this

`gcc (GCC) 5.3.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

It finds the gcc compiler. However, when I run it from my `msys2` Shell

`bash: gcc: command not found`

The path in Environment variables is correct. `C:\MinGW\bin`

Yet it canno't find gcc

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you running `./configure && make` in a `cygwin` environment or something similar such as window's linux subsystem? If yes, you need the gcc that comes with `cygwin` or Window's Linux Subsystem.

Comment: I'm on Win10 OS

Comment: Indeed you are. But `bash` is not native to Windows 10, so you must be running Window's subsystem for linux. Try installing gcc from within `bash`.

Comment: @alvits I did. I used this command `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` to install gcc packages, any other suggestions ?

Comment: When you are inside `bash`, what's the value of `$PATH`? Update the path to add the location of gcc  and other binutils. You'll need them all in make.

Comment: @alvits after trying `$PATH` I get this `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath/bin:/c/Program: No such file or directory` And for some reason I can't find here gcc. Is that the problem ? or am I missing something ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128760/discussion-between-tony-tannous-and-alvits).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The path to your `gcc` compiler is not in the `PATH`.

You may add it before you run make.

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/c/MinGW/bin
./configure && make
```

Goodluck.

Comment: For MinGW-w64 installed from [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org): `export PATH=$PATH:/mingw64/bin`.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm on Win10 OS

There is a [Visual Studio project file for the compiler](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/compiler/cpp/compiler.vcxproj). Either use that one, or [download the compiler binary for Windows directly from the website](https://thrift.apache.org/download).

Comment: Just got an upvote so I re read the thread, indeed having visual studio makes life easier. Had to install dlib package and had the same issure as this thread, worked out after installing visual studio 15

Answer (score 1):

If it is centos/redhat machine install full set of development package

```
$ sudo yum groups install "Development Tools"
```

it includes gcc,g++,make Id. After installing try again

Answer (score 0):

This tread is old, however, it worked for me by enabling "set MSYS2_PATH_TYPE=inherit" in the startup script. Running mingw64.exe in the root of MSYS2 worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

For the future: If on Windows 10 and MSYS2. I uncommented the line

```
set MSYS2_PATH_TYPE=inherit
```

on msys2_shell.cmd, so it just inherits the path where you put everything on windows.

I'm surprised this is not the default!