# error: 'strdup' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c, linux, apache, makefile, thrift

I am trying to Build and Install the Apache Thrift compiler and libraries

As shown in instructions run `./configure && make`

And I get this error:

```
thrift 0.9.3

Building C++ Library ......... : no
Building C (GLib) Library .... : no
Building Java Library ........ : no
Building C# Library .......... : no
Building Python Library ...... : no
Building Ruby Library ........ : no
Building Haxe Library ........ : no
Building Haskell Library ..... : no
Building Perl Library ........ : no
Building PHP Library ......... : no
Building Erlang Library ...... : no
Building Go Library .......... : no
Building D Library ........... : no
Building NodeJS Library ...... : no
Building Lua Library ......... : no

If something is missing that you think should be present,
please skim the output of configure to find the missing
component.  Details are present in config.log.
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/University/InternetOfThings/thrift-0.9.3'
Making all in compiler/cpp
make[2]: Entering directory '/c/University/InternetOfThings/thrift-0.9.3/compiler/cpp'
/bin/sh ../../ylwrap src/thrifty.yy y.tab.c src/thrifty.cc y.tab.h `echo src/thrifty.cc | sed -e s/cc$/hh/ -e s/cpp$/hpp/ -e s/cxx$/hxx/ -e s/c++$/h++/ -e s/c$/h/` y.output src/thrifty.output -- bison -y -d
updating src/thrifty.hh
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory '/c/University/InternetOfThings/thrift-0.9.3/compiler/cpp'
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../../lib/cpp/src/thrift  -I./src  -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused -g -O2 -std=c++11 -MT src/libparse_a-thrifty.o -MD -MP -MF src/.deps/libparse_a-thrifty.Tpo -c -o src/libparse_a-thrifty.o `test -f 'src/thrifty.cc' || echo './'`src/thrifty.cc
src/thrifty.yy: In function 'int yyparse()':
src/thrifty.yy:1311:30: error: 'strdup' was not declared in this scope
Makefile:912: recipe for target 'src/libparse_a-thrifty.o' failed
make[3]: *** [src/libparse_a-thrifty.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/c/University/InternetOfThings/thrift-0.9.3/compiler/cpp'
Makefile:588: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/University/InternetOfThings/thrift-0.9.3/compiler/cpp'
Makefile:609: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/University/InternetOfThings/thrift-0.9.3'
Makefile:530: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I edited thrifty.yy and added `#include <string.h>` yet I still get the same error that strdup is missing.

`src/thrifty.yy:1311:30: error: 'strdup' was not declared in this scope` (same error as before including string.h)

What am I missing here ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944390/what-is-the-rationale-for-not-including-strdup-in-the-c-standard

Comment: Anything related in  config.log?

Comment: Is that cygwin environment? Woudl be nice to know ... in that case look at [THRIFT-2800](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2800)

Comment: ... or use the [existing Windows binary](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40767099/499466).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`strdup` is not a standard C function. When a compiler is configured to be strict C compliant, it is not allowed to dump its own custom, non-standard functions in standard library headers like `<string.h>`.

You can resolve this by changing the compiler to compile non-standard C code (for example in gcc, compile with `-std=gnu11` instead of `-std=c11`). Or alternatively, stick to pure standard C.

---

... or just implement strdup yourself, it is easy:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* strdup (const char* s)
{
  size_t slen = strlen(s);
  char* result = malloc(slen + 1);
  if(result == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  memcpy(result, s, slen+1);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: @TonyTannous Don't compile C code with a C++ compiler. That being said, there's no reason why a C++ compiler wouldn't recognize pointers, more likely it doesn't recognize `<string.h>` but gives bad errors.

Comment: It is not me, all I did was ./configure && make as in the instructions.
https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/

Comment: I reopened the file and the only place I have a strdup is
`{     pdebug("TypeAnnotationValue ->");    $$ = strdup("1");
    }`

I will try to implement it otherway. Thanks though :)

Comment: Maybe it solves the actual problem, but it should not be necessary to fiddle with source or make files at all. That's very likely only a workaround, not the real solution.

Comment: I had to add a cast: `char* result = (char*) malloc(slen + 1);`

Comment: @robermann That's because you are using the wrong compiler. You shouldn't compile C code on a C++ compiler.

Comment: Actually I was trying to compile c++ code  ([this leveldb](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/leveldb/blob/bitcoin-fork/db/c.cc) on Windows + Cygwin); then I got the same OP's message. After your suggestion, I got:

    In function ‘char* strdup(const char*)’:
    error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
    char* result = malloc(slen + 1);

With the cast worked, but I got other problems (ok, C/C++ is not my main strength :))

Comment: @robermann C and C++ are two different languages, incompatible in numerous ways.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, in MakeFile by directory `/thrift-x.x.x/compiler/cpp/src` replace `-std=c++11` to `-std=gnu++11`

Answer (score 2):

./configure CXXFLAGS='-std=gnu++11' && make

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).